# cakephp save returns true but does not save

Tags: cakephp, save

CakePHP is driving me nuts!

Here is my code:

```
if($this->Page->save($datavalue))
{
$this->Session->setFlash('Page content updated successfully.');
}
else
{
$this->Session->setFlash('Page content was not updated.');
}
```

it always says updated successfully, but nothing is updated in the database.
Here is the content of $datavalue:

```
Array
(
    [Page] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => home
            [title] => Home page1
            [meta_keywords] => keyword1
            [meta_description] => this is home page
            [content] => home page content
            [sidebar] => sidebar content
        )

)
```

I am new to CakePHP, can you please give me a general idea of what could be wrong with it?

Thanks in advance.

### -happyhardik

Here is my model code:

```
<?php

class Page extends AppModel
{   
    var $name='Page';
    var $useTable = false;    
}
?>
```

Hope this helps!
I tried to add this two lines before save, in a hope that it will help:

```
$this->Page->set($datavalue);
$this->Page->id = $id;
```

but none of them helped.

---

Here is the table structure:

```
id               int(10) UNSIGNED  auto_increment  Primary
name             varchar(250) 
title            varchar(250) 
meta_keywords    text   
meta_description text
content          text 
sidebar          text
created          datetime
modified         datetime
```

Let me know, if need any more information.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Set debug to `2` in `core.php` and tell us what your SQL debug looks like.

Comment: Its set to 3, the bottom of the page says:
(default) 0 query took ms

Comment: Do you have any validation rules defined for Page?

Comment: Are you doing anything funky in the Page model, like overriding the `save()` method?

Comment: I don't have any validation or im not overiding the save method, check my model code above. I don't knw how to add funky stuff in Cake, as I am still figuring out what it is. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var $useTable = false;
```

Well, you're not using any table, which makes `save()` pretty much a NOOP. :-)

Remove that line and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Im having the same problem and google bring me here

I enabled `public $scaffold` and thus the save wont work.
just a reference incase anyone have the same problem